# String class regular expression difficulty

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the first word of astring containing alphanumeric  field

EG.

string can be 'abc123abc' or 'abc-123abc'
i just want the first 'abc'
is there any way to get it without for loop(I want to do this using regex but i don't know much about regular expression)

actually string pattern is like

```
[A-Za-z]{2,5}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,15}[A-Za-z]{0,15}
```

My aim is to get the first word

Comment: I tried using for loop which will split that word on occurence of any digit from 0-9 but it looks ugly

Comment: Actually your question is not very clear. You said you want the word from an alphanumeric string. But your second string contains a `hyphen`. So, which `abc` you want as output from it? The one before hyphen or the one after `123`?

Comment: @RohitJain :  I want first set of letters in case of 'abc123def' or 'abc-123def' i want only 'abc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as

```
System.out.println("abc-123abc".split("[-\\d]+")[0]);
```

output

```
abc
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the part of the expression that you would like to capture in a *capturing group*, and then use `group(1)` of the matcher to access it:

```
([A-Za-z]{2,5})-?[0-9]{1,15}[A-Za-z]{0,15}
```

The first group will capture everything up to the optional dash:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]{2,5})-?[0-9]{1,15}[A-Za-z]{0,15}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abc123abc");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The above prints `abc` ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/p9WiL7)).

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z]+
```

will match ASCII letters at the start of the string. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the matched text for `^[A-Za-z]{2,5}`. This will match all the first letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = "abc-123abc".replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z].*$", "");
```

This removes everything after the first non a-z character. You can also use replace with capturing groups.

```
String word = "abc-123abc".replaceFirst("^([a-zA-Z]+).*$", "$1");
```

[String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)